# Is there anywhere in the world I can still get a hot chocolate without a hechsher?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, travel, hechsher-certification

~150 years ago in [Eastern Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzhhorod), the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch wrote that you could usually go buy a coffee, tea, or hot chocolate without having to worry about its kosher ingredients (or bishul akum).  While this is mostly our practice today with regards to unflavored coffee or tea, I assume the hot chocolate available then was purely vegan; and today everyone would demand a hechsher on their hot chocolate given the possibility of animal-based flavorings, marshmallows (=gelatin), and the like.

Is there anywhere in the world (barring the use of a time machine) where you can still get a plain hot chocolate without a hechsher?

Comment: You can get a hot chocolate without a hechsher anywhere, it just might not be Kosher!

Comment: "Lo *suchal* lizboach es hapesach", and Onkelos translates "leis lach reshu" ...

Comment: You are welcome to come to my house!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.kosherstarbucks.com/Lists.asp

Comment: Wow, talk about too easy ...

Comment: Of course, the Starbucks actually has a hechsher on their mix.  I'd still be curious if there's anyplace vegan enough you could rely on an "unhechshered" chocolate; but YDK's answer gives me only 11,000 locations in the USA ... nebuch ...

Comment: Page Can't be found... What was the link?

Answer (score 5):

Places in India where Jainism is wide spread will provide you with animal free hot-choclates.